# Hide software keyboard for custom control with UIKeyInput

Tags: ios, keyboard

I need to implement a control similar to passcode entry on the device, but for convenience I wanted to add support of hardware keyboard too.

I can get the keystrokes from the keyboard using `UIKeyInput` protocol, but couldn't find a nice way of hiding software keyboard that automatically pops up.

I can think of some workaround by placing `UITextField` somewhere and assigning an empty view to `inputView`, but in `UIView` this property is read-only.

Is there a nice way to disable software keyboard but still have `UIKeyInput`?